# AMD equivalent of the CUDA Driver API?

Tags: cuda, opencl

CUDA has both runtime API and driver API. What is equivalent to this in AMD?. Can I get more control if I somehow modify the IL in llvm?

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit more? You seem to be conflating host side APIs with GPU code. The equivalent of the CUDA driver API on ATI would be the openCL API. They are both at about the same level and provide the same level of control and verbosity over GPU operations. But what do you think they have to do with IL, which is for writing GPU side code?

Comment: Thank you, that cleared it.I thought that had different levels of control. I was wondering if I could modify the AMD IL, just like modifying PTX for NVIDIA. Can I stop the compiling process at AMD IL, before it sends anything to CAL

Answer (score 5):

The analog of the CUDA driver API on the AMD platform is OpenCL. I am aware of no analog of the CUDA *runtime* API on the AMD platform at this time.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the closest match to the NVIDIA CUDA driver API would be [AMD CAL](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/amdappsdk/assets/AMD_CAL_Programming_Guide_v2.0.pdf) which ships with the [AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/downloads/Pages/default.aspx). AMD CAL does not only offer a more low-level host API than OpenCL, but also a more low-level compute kernel language called AMD IL, which also is the intermediate language OpenCL compiles to.

Comment: CAL is  deprecated. Hasn't changed for years, does not support GCN, deleted from latest APP SDK. http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/160049 http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/158980

Comment: Right. BTW, although this probably slightly too high-level, there now is [AMD Mantle](http://semiaccurate.com/2013/09/30/amds-mantle-biggest-change-gaming-decade/) which might be worth a look.

Comment: Mantle will probably be as low-level as CAL and very well supported. But I'd be very cautious in using it. The fact that it's proprietary is bad, but much worse is that it's tied to the GCN architecture (and will be for the next 10+ years as long as Xbox One and PS4 are sold). Should AMD's PC architecture change, Mantle will break or perform sub-optimally. In short, abstraction layers are good.